# How to prevent NetworkManager from changing iptables?

Tags: network-manager, iptables

Every time I turn on/off a device in my local network the `NetworkManager` automatically adds/removes the set of rules in `iptables`. 
The extracts from `/var/log/syslog`:

```
NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1576899905.0615] Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface wlp1s0 --protocol tcp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1576899905.0639] Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert INPUT --in-interface wlp1s0 --protocol udp --destination-port 53 --jump ACCEPT
...
NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1576899905.0748] Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --in-interface wlp1s0 --out-interface wlp1s0 --jump ACCEPT
NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1576899905.0768] Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --source 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --in-interface wlp1s0 --jump ACCEPT
NetworkManager[799]: <info>  [1576899905.0787] Executing: /sbin/iptables --table filter --insert FORWARD --destination 10.42.0.0/255.255.255.0 --out-interface wlp1s0 --match state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED --jump ACCEPT
...
```

Some of those rules conflict with my own rules because it always adds them in the beginning of the list. I didn't manage to find the files which contain these rules to change them. So how to stop these unwanted injections?
Ubuntu 18.04.3

Comment: Configure network without using NM in `/etc/network/interfaces`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkManager does so because you activate a profile with `ipv4.method=shared`.

This basically means to run dnsmasq as DHCP server and enable NAT/masquerading.

It is a simple thing, for simple usecases. I probably wouldn't use this as DHCP server for my infrastructure, but I would use it to quickly share the internet for another host. Possibly this could be extended in the future with more flexibility and features, but until now it's simple.

If it doesn't do what you want, don't use it. That means, don't activate a profile with "ipv4.method=shared`.

Comment: Yeah. This parameter was responsible for that behavior. Thank you. But there is a problem. I also use the WiFi Hotspot connection and it has only two 
 active parameters: shared and disabled. I tried to configure it directly  (/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot) and there was no success.